# $n$-connected spaces (terminology)

Tags: gn.general-topology, terminology, continuum-theory

A graph is called *$n$-connected* if it remains connected after removal $\le n$ vertices.

> **Question.** What is the name of an analogous property of topological spaces: a space that remains connected after removal of $\le n$ points.

Unfortunately, the term *$n$-connected space* is already occupied for naming topological spaces whose homotopy groups $\pi_k(X)$ are trivial for all $k\le n$.

Comment: For graphs, you have slightly different notions of k-vertex-connected (often shortened to just k-connected) and k-edge-connected ones. Why not borrow unabbreviated vertex-connectedness? Graph-theoretic definition is what you want verbatim.

Comment: @DenisT Thanks for the suggestion, which I have used (i.e., vertex-connected). In fact I needed only 1-connected spaces, which became vertex-connected.